# Shouldn't the better duplicates become the main answer?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, duplicate-questions

I am not a regular user of meta SO, and this is a naive idea.

I have seen several cases of duplicates questions that were:

- Better phrased than the original one
- More in the current technological context/trend
- With better examples
- With a more clear/comprehensive/generic answer(s)

And last but not least, many duplicates are ranked before originals on search engines.

After some time (to be determined) and some fulfilled criterions, shouldn't these answers be switched with what is considered the main one, or at least un-tagged as duplicate? Or maybe tagged as "related" but that would be another feature-request discussion.

Comment: The guidance is already to favor the better question, irrespective of dates.

Comment: This is not the better duplicate.  And should therefore not be marked as the canonical question.  Duplicate answers are okay.  Ish.